# Regular Expressions in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, expression, regular-language, qregularexpression

I hope you are well. So, as you can see, from "a-z" I have made a code to transcript every common letter (from "a" to "z") in some symbols. How can I do it when I want to transcript the letters "th" together in different symbol? I do not want the app to translate the letters "t" and "h" separately BUT together! How can I do that? Thank you so much!!!

var theInput = txtBr.value.toLowerCase();

```
for (var i = 0; i < theInput.length; i++)

 {
   
  
  var letter = theInput.charAt( i );
    
  if( letter.match(/[a-z\s]/i) ) {
    
    
    var symbol = map[ letter ];
    
    
    txtarea.innerHTML += symbol;
    
  }
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. This means adding `map` dictionary, and some examples of expected output.

Comment: Dear, Welcome to Stack overflow. Please don't use sentences that are in form of a meeting dialogue( like "I hope you are well. So, as you can see, from "a-z"). these kind of extra and unnecessary things will make your questions or answers edited by the community. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`string.search()` will return the position of the substring you are searching for.

```js
let string = "nspoiuthpiifs"; 
let position = string.search("th"); // will return 6
```

You could then split the string at that position with `string.split()`, replace the the "th" with the symbol you desire, then rejoin the string with `array.join()`

***Note:*** `string.search()` will return only the position of the *first* one it finds, so you may want to repeat this method until there are none left.

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer and time, but, i am too amateur and I cannot understand how to write in my code whatever you said.